# How to create login depended menu in HTML using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have several menu's in my project. Now I want to add another menu **UserMenu** [UserMenu title will replace by login user name], with some submenu's such as: view profile, edit profile and logout.

That means I want to keep this menu hidden until a user logged in. A user who does not login will show all menu's except **UserMenu** and a user will show every menu's including the **UserName** menu.

My logic was: selecting user_id when a user is logged in and store the user_id as PHP session varialble. When the PHP session variable has a value than the **UserMenu** will visible else hidden.

But the problem is, I am using jQuery for the login form validation purpose, and I think it is not possible to set PHP session variable using jQuery or JavaScript.

Can anyone please tell me how can I implement the dynamic menu based on login using PHP? A better idea is welcome.
- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After logging the user, try using ajax request to get the menu from php:

get_usermenu.php:

```
<?php
//Show only if user id exists
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"]))
{
    echo "Menu content goes here...";
}
?>
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({url: "get_usermenu.php", success: function(result){
    $("#usermenu").html(result);
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

> DO NOT validate through jQuery under any circumstances! Client validation can very easily be hacked. Make sure you do validation via PHP.

As @Manikiran said, using an `if(isset($value))` check is a way to load in certain things for a user.

My advice is to use jQuery's [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function to send requests to server code, validate it, and then return the code using `echo json_encode($value)` in the PHP file.

You are also correct about not being able to use PHP sessions in JavaScript. PHP Sessions are handled by the server before the code is sent to the user. And even if JavaScript could validate PHP Sessions, you would never want to put server information in the hands of the browser and the client.

Hope this helped bot you and future Googlers.